# Print Global variable in view using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app with a global variable(actual global variable, not `$rootScope`). I need to print it to the view using the `{{  }}` expression. How can I associate a `$scope` variable of current controller to thisglobal variable, such that I always have the latest value of this global variable printed on screen.

EDIT: Code:

```
app.controller('placesCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope',function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.place = place;
}]);

var autocomplete,map,place = {};
place.name = "asdf";
function initAutocomplete() {
    ...

    //Initialize google maps autocomplete
    //Add event listener

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {

    //update place            
        place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        console.log(place);

        if (!place.geometry) {
            window.alert("No such city found!");
            return;
        }

      });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `myGlobal` is an object, a simple reference to it is enough:

```
$rootScope.myGlobal = myGlobal;
```

Now if it's a raw value such as a string or number (or if you change the reference of your object), you could use a closure on it:

```
$rootScope.getMyGlobal = function() { return myGlobal; }
```

And then in your HTML write:

```
<div>{{getMyGlobal()}}</div>
```

Comment: Should note that until a new digest cycle executes, getMyGlobal() will not get called so the expression will not be updated till then. So if the global variable gets updated outside of some angular process it will not be updated on screen till the next cycle

Comment: @PatrickEvans right, thanks for pointing that out. So if the code updating the variable is not within the Angular lifecycle, for instance in some asynchronous request, don't forget to call `$scope.$apply` around or after it.

Comment: Well if they have access to `$scope` they should really be updating that, and not some global variable. My warning was more about if they update their variable completely outside Angular, for instance in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jhx8Lgqm/), a setTimeout changes the variable but has no access to `$scope.apply()` so the view isnt updated till some random digest occurs

Comment: @floribon this doesn't work for me. I have created a function `$scope.city = function(){ return place.name; }` and have a `h1` set up in the controller as `<h1>{{city()}}</h1>`. I get no errors and no output values.  while when I log the value of place, it gives the correct output.

Comment: I agree the use case is weird and certainly not recommended, but for general Angular understanding it's a good exercice. In your example indeed nothing else can be done (let's avoid mentioning `$setInterval`).

Comment: @ayushgp it looks like you are indeed manipualting an object. Could you set `$scope.place = place` and bind `{{place.name}}` in your HTML? If this doesn't work we'd need to see more of your code. Best if you can reproduce it in a jsfiddle or something

Comment: @PatrickEvans The fiddle you showed, that is exactly my case. Any method to do that?

Comment: @ayushgp couldn't you move all your code within your controller? Or do you have strong requirements to keep them separated? You can't really expect to have a robust angular application if the logic happens elsewhere. For this very case, you could maybe use `autocomplete.addListener` in your controller to trigger a `scope.$apply` every time an event happens? Otherwise if you have at least access to angular from your code, you could hack something like `angular.element('body').scope().$apply()`

Answer (score 2):

template should always bind to a child scope of `$rootScope`, so you should set a function in child scope to retrieve data from `$rootScope`:

```
//controller
$scope.getData = function(){
    return gloablData;
}

//template
<div>{{getData()}}</div>
```

Comment: it **isn't** a property of `$rootScope` but an actual global variable

Comment: then simply return the global data in `getData`